# CyberSource Payment Processor Transaction Inquiry using SOAP

Tags: soap, paypal

Wondering if anyone has any info regarding CyberSource...

What I am trying to accomplish is a SOAP request to perform an inquiry.

Looking for any documentation and/or examples on how to perform a SOAP request using either the merchantReferenceCode or preferably the requestToken or requestID to check the status of the transaction.

Thanks I really appreciate it!

Comment: May be you already found relevant information ,, but below docs provides a better understanding

http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Simple_Order_API_Clients/Client_SDK_SO_API.pdf?searchid=1500941989998

Comment: Nuwan - yes I have found a solution...turns out the simple order API is simply for CRUD operations relating to transactions etc. When looking to obtain transaction details such as current status of an authorization etc. one must utilize CyberSource's xml/json reporting service; this service is hosted on a different endpoint and uses a basic authentication header when performing a GET with application/x-www-form-urlencoded data. The report I am pulling from the service is the transaction detail report. Hope this info helps others looking to get details given a specific Request ID. 
~Tony